# Regex Match all character until ti reaches a number

Tags: python, regex

I just recently came across regex. To be honest, regex scares me sometimes hehe but I'm trying my best to learn it. So, I had ask a question about it before and now I'm here again with another question. I have the following sample data and what I would like to do is to select everything before the numbers.

```
pencil apple car 15 Nate
beef sun shirt 56 Gaile
face building air 36 Ron
```

so my desired output would be

```
pencil apple car
beef sun shirt
face building air
```

I tried this :

```
.+?(?=[\d])
```

But that only selects the first line. Thanks for your answers!
EDIT: Im using python by the way.

Comment: you can add the *multiline* flag. Please check the API of the library you are using to check how to. Besides, you didn't specify the language so can't help you more than that.

Comment: *"EDIT: Im using python by the way."* in this case add the python tag to your question and add the python code you use.

Comment: Also, what is the expected result if there's no number?

Comment: I'm basing my sample data to a live data and every line has a number into it so your question is not applicable. Just needed the mutiline flag as some had suggested. As I said on my initial post, I am quite new to this so yeah..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anchor your match to start of line (`^` is start of *line* when you use the multi-line flag), and match non-digits:

```
(?m)^\D*
```

Replace the match with a blank to delete it.

Update:
To get everything up to but not including the last digit, use a look ahead:

```
(?m)^.*(?=\d)
```

Comment: As easy as that. Thanks a bunch

Comment: Just a follow up, for the data "juice 12 plane face building air 36 Ron" the match ends in juice instead of air?

Answer (score 0):

If you would match the text until you encounter those numbers or all the text, you might use a word boundary `\b` and an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to match any character until you encounter a word boundary followed by a digit using a positive lookahead, or match not a digit or a new line.

`^(?:.*(?=\b\d)|[^\d\n]+)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VIK49y/1)

If you do want to match a new line you could use `\D+` instead of `[^\d\n]+`